# Python syntax error "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I found this script on the internet:
https://gist.github.com/gavsmi/dd31746e5847300b62da

Any idea why I am getting the following error message? It looks like a syntax error. I am still new to Python, so please help me point out what the problem is and how to fix it.

```
[root@ip-172-31-18-97 tmppython]# python snapshot.py
INFO:root:Finding snapshot for tag...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snapshot.py", line 164, in <module>
    main()
  File "snapshot.py", line 30, in main
    snapshot = find_snapshot(args.tag_name, args.tag_value)
  File "snapshot.py", line 47, in find_snapshot
    snapshots = conn.get_all_snapshots(filters={'tag:' + tag_name: tag_value})
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Comment: It is not a syntax errror, it is a runtime error. `tag_name` is `None`, not a string.

Comment: *Why* the error occurs, would require debugging, but Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. You do need to do some work up front yourself. For example, you need to tell us what your code is supposed to do, what you expect to happen and where you think the problem may lie. Also see [Are there legitimate "fix my code" questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253787) and the linked [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog post.

Comment: A quick glance at the traceback shows that the `--tag-name` command line switch is not optional. The code broke here because there is no tag name specified.

Answer (score 0):

You likely are not providing a 'tag_name' command line argument when running your script. Added arguments default to None in the argparse module, so 'args.tag_name' ('tag_name' in the scope where the error occurs) will be None unless you give it a value via the command line. If it is not clear, the “cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects” run-time error results from the attempted concatenation "'tag:' + tag_name", where 'tag_name' is None.